# How can I UV map this texture onto this model?

Tags: texturing, uv

[[image: Stack1]

I have a texture that is 2048x2048 pixels and 1 material assigned to my mesh. How can I arrange the UV map so that every "floor" looks different; with properly scaled texture?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make any of the UV faces larger than the texture quadrant, if that makes sense. So you can make each UV face fill up the whole corner, like this:

[image]

And then you can stack all the faces on top of each other:

[image]

But you can't make any faces larger than the UV layout because of the way your texture is created.

If you need to scale the textures smaller, you need to subdivide into more faces.

Otherwise you need to separate into 4 textures, because a single texture can repeat, like this:

[image]

With 4 textures in one, you can't do that.

Comment: How can I use multiple textures onto 1 mesh with 1 material?  (in this case)

Comment: I think you need 4 materials.  Is there a reason you can only have 1 material?